# Error when running make for my Makefile.cpp

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm getting the error "No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop." 
however I'm running the "make" command for my Makefile.cpp in the same directory.

So I just wanted to do a simple makefile to run my three separate files:

```
all:
        g++ gameoflife.cpp functions.cpp header.hpp -o gameoflife
```

The second line is tabbed once.

Let me know if I need to rename the files or how exactly to run the make file correctly. Thanks. Also this is all being run in a UNIX server with make installed, etc.

Comment: `mv Makefile.cpp Makefile && make all`

Comment: This makefile isn't making use of the benefits of make at all but that's not the issue. The issue is, as @juanchopanza says, that make doesn't look for `Makefile.cpp` it looks for `makefile` and `Makefile` (and `GNUMakefile`).

Comment: @juanchopanza The `all` isn't necessary, is it? ;-)

Comment: Okay, I changed it, but now it outputs g++ gameoflife.cpp -o gameoflife then I still need to type ./gameoflife shouldn't the makefile just start the program after typing make all? @juanchopanza all is not required but it still does what I stated above

Comment: Not unless you have a target run the program for you. You can do that. Your makefile doesn't.

Comment: _`g++ gameoflife.cpp functions.cpp header.hpp `_ << You don't compile header files, you `#include "header.hpp"` from source.

Comment: I'm also getting the expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The make command uses the makefile with the the name that you specify with the -f option. If you don't use the -f options it uses the file `Makefile` without the `.cpp` appendix.

Your editor might have save your `Makefile` as `Makefile.cpp`. Check that you use the correct name.

Edit:

To be more specific: The [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Makefile-Arguments) searches for one of these files in that order:

- GNUmakefile
- makefile
- Makefile

Comment: `Makefile` is one of a number of names that `GNU Make` looks for.